# snort flowbits and tag rules don't work

Tags: snort

**I have the following two rules**

```
alert tcp any any -> 192.168.2.105 80 (msg:"test-tag"; sid:10000;flow:from_client;flowbits:set,http;tag:session,exclusive;)

alert tcp 192.168.2.105 80 -> any any (msg:"test-triggered";sid:10001;flowbits:isset,http;tag:session,exclusive;)
```

then I used curl on another machine to send request to `192.168.2.105:80`, and I can see that the first alert rule triggered; but the second alert rule wasn't triggered, I don't know why.Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The flow of the communication was from any IP with any port to `192.168.2.105` port 80. The second rule specifies the flow from `192.168.2.105` 80 to any IP with any port.

If you changed the -> to <> in both rules they should both trigger an alert.